# Linq - Trying to filter out the Eager Selection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to filter out the second part of the tables (UserRoles.IsDeleted==false). Is there any advice how i can do that?

```
var Users = context.Users.Where(r => r.IsDeleted == IsDeleted).ToList<User>();
Users = context.Users.Include(x => x.UserRoles.Select(y=>y.IsDeleted==false)).ToList();
```

Thank you

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish. You can turn off lazy loading if that's a problem, or you can join on the UserRoles if that's what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to filter using the second part:

```
var Users = context.Users.Where(r => r.IsDeleted == IsDeleted).ToList<User>();

if(condition)
{
    Users = Users.where(y => y.IsDeleted == false)).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to filter related entities

Doing a projection.
Unfortunately, when you use `Include` method, you can't filter the related entities as you intend to do. You need to project your query to a DTO object or a anonymous object, as the below example.

```
var query=context.Users.Include(x => x.UserRoles)
                       .Where(r => r.IsDeleted == IsDeleted)
                       .Select(u=> new{ ..., 
                                       Roles=x => x.UserRoles.Where(y=>!y.IsDeleted)})
```

A second option could be using [Explicitly Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx). But this is in case you can load the related entities of one specific entity,eg,.

```
var user=context.Users.FirstOrDefault(r.IsDeleted == IsDeleted);//Getting a user

context.Entry(user) 
        .Collection(b => b.UserRoles) 
        .Query() 
        .Where(y=>!y.IsDeleted)
        .Load();
```

You can do this inside of a foreach per each entity you get from the first query,

```
 var query=context.Users.Where(r => r.IsDeleted == IsDeleted);
 foreach(var u in query)
 {
  context.Entry(u) 
         .Collection(b => b.UserRoles) 
         .Query() 
         .Where(y=>!y.IsDeleted)
         .Load(); 

 }
```

but it's going to be really inefficient because you are going to do a roundtrip to your DB per each entity. My advice is use the first option, projecting the query.